# Как сделать пагинацию таблицы?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pagination

Пишу на objective-c. Нужно сделать чтобы таблица выводилась не полностью, а частями. Я знаю что нужно делать: сначала загружать 10 элементов, потом, когда таблица будет доскроливаться к низу, просить подгрузить следующие 10 элементов. Но я не знаю как это сделать. Кто знает как это реализовать, пожалуйста помогите. Если можно, то с примерами.

Comment: объявить себя делегатом и в методе `-scrollViewDidScroll:` смотреть, что оффсет дошел до низа экрана и делать что надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть уже готовые решения, такие как [`SVPullToRefresh`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh), писать что то свое, конечно хорошо, но все же лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, это сэкономит и ваше время, и время тестировщиков, если таковы имеются, т.е., будет время заняться другими вещами.

Comment: Вы правы! Зачем изобретать велосипед, если уже есть готовые библиотеки. Это то что мне нужно, огромное спасибо.